# Where is Waze Beacon installed?

Tags: gps-navigation, tunnels

I understand that [Waze has installed beacons in many tunnels around the world](https://support.google.com/waze/partners/answer/9416071?hl=en&ref_topic=7300537). These beacons apparently use Bluetooth to replace the GPS signals, since GPS does not work in tunnels. In other words, Waze users with Bluetooth enabled can continue to receive navigation directions inside tunnels that have the Waze Beacons installed.

Is there any listing or map that documents all the tunnels where Waze Beacon is functional?

Comment: Have you asked Waze?

Comment: From what I understand, it’s not Waze installing them, it’s the cities (or other infrastructure operators) which chose to partner with Waze. There are a few press releases here and there about such partnerships, but at first glance it seems relatively limited.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic as it’s not about travel.

Comment: I would certainly think that GPS navigation through tunnels in unfamiliar cities is certainly a question about travel. At least, it certainly concerns MY kind of travel.

Comment: @jcaron Whether installation is limited or not, Waze will know where they area. They may not tell us or the OP, but they'll know.